# Not able to satisfy NSLayoutConstraints while setting it programatically

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to give constraints to a label -> `dateLabel` inside a view, these are the constraints I've given:

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel,
attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: summaryView, 
attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel, 
attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: summaryView, attribute:
.topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0)
```

Also, I've added these constraints to my view like -> `summaryView.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])`

But I'm getting a message saying `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add width and height constraints?

Comment: Did not add that to the label. Is that necessary though?

Comment: Yes. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Have you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`?

Comment: Actually you giving relation between both vies to be zero and then adding some constant, try with zero constant.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR, I tried it, still getting the same error.

Comment: Give us the **full** warning you are getting. While very ugly, these **do** give us everything needed to see the exact issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thank you so much! It worked after I set the label to `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints`! Also, it would be great if you could tell me what it actually does, If its not too much trouble.

Comment: When you add a UIView programatically, that property is set to true by default. It tells the system to,add constraints that implement the value set in the view's `frame`. This ensure that code written before autolayout continues to operate correctly with autolayout. When you add your own constraints these will conflict with the ones that are added automatically so you set the property to false or prevent those constraints from being created.

Comment: Also show us how `summaryView` is created. If the frame is `.zero` at initialization it could cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

if your label is a programmatically you must call `summaryView.addConstraints` after `summaryView.addSubview(label)`

Comment: That is what I've done. I've added the label to the view, my last statement of the method is the `addConstraints` actually.

Comment: try this `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])` or use 
[MisterFusion](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/MisterFusion)